# How can i implement this query in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm beginner in `sql server`,have two table ,table `GetOnlineBills` with this shape:

```
--Telno--      --Cycle--      --Bill--
nchar(20)       nchar(20)       float
```

And table `25Percantage`:

```
--Telno--      --Cycle--      --Bill--
nchar(20)       nchar(20)       float
```

want to write query or `tsql` for analysis `Telno` in `GetOnlineBill` table with this flow:

```
1-fetch Telno ang get it bill value in Cycle 951 and Cycle 952
2-If Bill(952)>Bill(951) then write into 25 percantage this data (Bill(952)-Bill(951))
```

into GetOnlineBill's table write subscribe Bill information per cycle,For example have two subscribe(in really world have 1 million subscribe) with this plan:
into the `GetOnlineBills` one mounth data is this:

```
    --Telno--      --Cycle--      --Bill--
      12345           951           300
      54321           951           500
```

and other month data is :

```
--Telno--      --Cycle--      --Bill--
  12345            952            400
  54321            952            600
```

and final `GetOnlineBill` for two mounth is:

```
    --Telno--       --Cycle--      --Bill--
      12345            951            300
      54321            951            500
      12345            952            400
      54321            952            600
```

Now,i want analysis `GetOnlineBill`,want write query or `tsql` to create final `25Percantage` table show me this:

```
--Telno--      --Cycle--      --Bill--
  12345          951-952         100 ------>Bill(952)-Bill(951) Minus
  54321          951-952         300

  ----------------------------------------

  Explain:
  Bill:Field Name on GetOnlineBill table
  952:Cycle
  951:Cycle
```

How can i write query or `tsql` for that purpose?please write and post me.thanks all.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You've shown no SQL of your own, and... StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service. I suggest editing your question to show what you've done, the output, etc.

Comment: How do you find `300` for this  `54321          951-952         300`?

Comment: @NEER thanks for pay attention to my problem,300 is Minus Bill field GetonlineBill in cycle(952) - bill field GetonlineBill in cycle(951) result

Comment: @NEER sorry I made a mistake!,600-500=100 is correct!

Comment: If `Bill(952) < Bill(951)` What will you do?

Comment: @DavidMakogon correct,but my friend i'm beginner and need to solve this problem.

Comment: Huh, Price is float...

Comment: @NEER If Bill(952) < Bill(951) means when analysis, if that condition (Bill field on getonlinebill table in cycle(952)>cycle(951) is true then minus two field

Comment: @dean my friend if If I knew it sql server,i'm not to point beginner!

Comment: In short, never use float for anything financial or otherwise deterministic; use decimal/numneric instead.

Comment: @dean thanks,ok i alter the table ,how can i solve main problem?!

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi Which DBMS you use?

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi there are dozens, if not hundreds, of SQL tutorials on the web. If you are a beginner, there are plenty of resources to learn from. Meanwhile, your question doesn't fit within the guidelines of stack overflow. And you've now turned the comment section into a discussion.

Comment: @DavidMakogon ok,but i must solve that problem now!,dont have a time for read tutorial,i'm behind the server!

Comment: @NEER Sql server 2014

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi And that's another thing: This isn't a paid service, and *nobody* is obligated to help you solve your problem **now**. This is a site supported by volunteers, not on-demand programmers. Sorry that you don't have time to read a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner join should help you:

```
SELECT  y.Telno,
        t.Cycle+'-'+y.Cycle Cycle,
        y.Bill - t.Bill Price
FROM YourTable y
INNER JOIN YourTable t
    ON y.Telno = t.TelNo AND CAST(y.Cycle as int)-1 = CAST(t.Cycle as int)
```

Output:

```
Telno   Cycle   Price
12345   951-952 100
54321   951-952 100
```

If `Cycle` column can not be converted to `integer` then you need some other field to order table right way and do join with that field (or OUTER APPLY)

Comment: thanks for answer,that's work,but how can i insert that select query 25Percantage table?

Comment: Nice if it works. The second part of your comment is not understandable, what do you mean by *but how can i insert that select query 25Percantage table?*? It is another question?

Answer (score 0):

Try as the below:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (TelNo NCHAR(20), Cycle NCHAR(20), Bill FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @Tbl
VALUES  
('12345', '951', 300),
('12345', '952', 400),
('54321', '951', 500),
('54321', '952', 600)

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Cycle) MonthId  
    FROM @Tbl
)

SELECT 
    CurrentMonth.TelNo,
    CurrentMonth.Cycle + '-' + NextMonth.Cycle Cycle,
    CASE 
        WHEN NextMonth.Bill > CurrentMonth.Bill THEN NextMonth.Bill - CurrentMonth.Bill
        ELSE CurrentMonth.Bill END Bill -- Change as you want
FROM 
    CTE CurrentMonth LEFT JOIN 
    CTE NextMonth ON CurrentMonth.TelNo = NextMonth.TelNo AND (NextMonth.MonthId - 1) = CurrentMonth.MonthId
WHERE
    NextMonth.MonthId IS NOT NULL
```

Result:

```
TelNo                Cycle                    Bill
-------------------- ------------------------ ---------
54321                951-952                  100
12345                951-952                  100
```